# Adding url to the Parsed Json data

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Using the Blogger API, I am displaying the title of trending articles of my blog in a list view. In the JSON response, I also get the URL of the corresponding post. What I want to do is add this corresponding URL to the title, so that when the user clicks on the title, the linked post opens up in a browser.
How can I achieve this?

My MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    String baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/6648452808939065157/posts";
    String apiKey = "?key=" + BuildConfig.API_KEY;
    String blogUrl =  (baseUrl.concat(apiKey));

    //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetItems().execute();
    }

    public void item_click(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ContentActivity.class));
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
     HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

     // Making a request to url and getting response
     String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(blogUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

     if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray items = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items");

                    // looping through Latest Articles
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                        String title = c.getString("title");
                        String post_url = c.getString("url");




                        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        item.put("title", title);
                        item.put("url",post_url);

                        // adding item to article list
                        itemList.add(item);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    itemList,R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"title"},
                    new int[]{R.id.title});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code as opposed to providing an external link.  This improvement will help future readers of your question find an answer in case the link doesn't work in that future and they have a similar issue.

Comment: done...added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an `OnClickListener` on your title in your ListView adapter. This is easily achievable by setting `yourTextView.setClickable(true);` followed by `yourTextView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);`.

I see that you passed the entire `hashedMap itemList` parsed JSON data to your `SimpleAdapter` constructor. In your `SimpleAdapter`, within your `OnClickListener`, you can use a `WebView` and display the URL by retrieving it from the HashMap. You can get the clicked position by using `getAdapterPosition()`. Updating your post with your SimpleAdapter code would also help.